# Grid not working in java swing and getting overflowed

Tags: java, swing

I have a Jframe and I want to show grids as follows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmXPJ.png]

There are 3rows and in the 2nd row there are **two columns**.So,but when I add a Jlabel and Jtextfield  in 2nd row,then the 2nd column of 2nd grid goes below the 2nd row and acts as 3rd column. For eg:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0qUZ.png]

So `"hello55"` needs to come side by side of the 2nd row,but it is coming downward as extra row in swing. How can I make it side to side?

So,I tried as:

```
public class AdminDashboard extends JFrame {
    
     
    private JPanel panel,subPanel1;
    
    public AdminDashboard() {
        System.out.println("hello");
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1000, 609);
        panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,5,10));
        JLabel labe11=new JLabel("hello11");
        JLabel labe12=new JLabel("hello22");
        JLabel labe13=new JLabel("hello33");
        JLabel labe14=new JLabel("hello44");
        JLabel labe15=new JLabel("hello55");

        panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        panel.add(labe11);
        
        
        subPanel1 = new JPanel(); // sub-panel 1
        
        subPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2,5,10));
        //creating form for 2nd row 1st column
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        subPanel1.add(userLabel);

        JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100, 10, 80, 25);
        subPanel1.add(userText);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        subPanel1.add(passwordLabel);

        JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
        subPanel1.add(passwordText);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
        loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        subPanel1.add(loginButton);
        
        JButton registerButton = new JButton("register");
        registerButton.setBounds(180, 80, 80, 25);
        subPanel1.add(registerButton);
        
        //2nd row 2nd column
        subPanel1.add(labe15);
        
        
      
        subPanel1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        subPanel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel.add(subPanel1);
        
        panel.add(labe13);
        

        add(panel);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Your description of the problem is not very clear. I don't know what you mean by second row and third row etc. In your picture I see 6 rows. But the basic answer to your question is to use more nested panels and/or use a different layout manager. I would suggest a `GridBagLayout` might be easier than trying to force everything into multiple GridLayouts.  Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information.

Comment: Also, get rid of the `setBounds()` statements. They are unnecessary. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location of a component. Setting the component orientation is also unnecessary.

Comment: Ok then can u help me to get the same layout using gridbaglayout?

Comment: There are total 3rows but i created subpanel for 2nd row and there are two rows in second row but due to the addition of my form, the 2nd column of 2nd row is going beyond the 2nd row. Pleawe see the attached images

Comment: I'm still not understanding your terminology of 2nd, 3rd row etc. Be specific. Are you trying to have the "hello55" button display beside the "register" button? if so then make that panel use a GridLayout of 3 columns. I can't help you with the GridBagLayout. I gave you a tutorial link for you to read. There is demo code to download. Play with the code and modify it for your requirement. Layout of the screen is done by using multiple panels each can use a specific layout. So design your layout and then design which panels and layout manager you want for each panel.

Comment: Do you want something like this image: https://imgur.com/a/y1GEIkM

Comment: yes exactly the image you posted

Comment: i tried using gridbagcomponent from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java but after button4 i tried to add a new column c.gridx = 1;
 c.gridy = 2; but it didnot worked. please can u help me

Comment: yes @Abra same as you posted please help me.. if possible with gridbagcomponent. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code simply sets up your desired GUI and nothing more. It is not a complete, working application. Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class AdminDashboard implements Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createBottomPanel() {
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel hello33 = new JLabel("hello33");
        bottomPanel.add(hello33);
        return bottomPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createFormPanel() {
        JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 5;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
        formPanel.add(userLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        JTextField userTextField = new JTextField(6);
        formPanel.add(userTextField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        formPanel.add(passwordLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(6);
        formPanel.add(passwordField, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
        formPanel.add(loginButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        JButton registerButton = new JButton("register");
        formPanel.add(registerButton, gbc);

        return formPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 10));
        mainPanel.add(createFormPanel());
        mainPanel.add(createTablePanel());
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTablePanel() {
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel hello55 = new JLabel("hello55");
        tablePanel.add(hello55);
        return tablePanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTopPanel() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel hello11 = new JLabel("hello11");
        topPanel.add(hello11);
        return topPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Admin Dashboard");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTopPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createBottomPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Start here.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new AdminDashboard());
    }
}
```

The default layout manager for the content pane of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`. So I placed the *hello11* as the top component and the *hello33* as the bottom component.

In the center component I put a panel and set its layout manager to `GridLayout` so that I could nest within it two panels side by side where the left panel is your form and the right panel is *hello55*.

For the panel displaying the [login] form, I used `GridBagLayout`.

Here is a screen capture of the window displayed when running the above code.

[image: Admin_Dashboard]

Comment: thank u for ur tym i will ask u if there is some confusion

Answer (score -1):

If is this what you want to do:
[image: registration form]

```java
public class Registration extends Application {

    // Defines the text fields and respective label components that will be used. 
    private TextField loginField;
    private TextField nameField;
    private TextField cpfField;
    private TextField emailField;
    private TextField addressField;
    
    private PasswordField passwordField;

    private Label passwordLabel;
    private Label nameLabel;
    private Label cpfLabel;
    private Label emailLabel;
    private Label addressLabel;

    private Button submit;
    private Button cancel;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        // Sets top title
        primaryStage.setTitle("Registration");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Defines the gap between grid components
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);

        // Defines our window size
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 900, 500);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

        // Defines the label names and add them to the grid
        Label header = new Label("Registration");
        grid.add(header, 1, 0, 2, 1);

        nameLabel = new Label("Name:");
        grid.add(nameLabel, 0, 1);

        emailLabel = new Label("Email:");
        grid.add(emailLabel, 0, 2);

        passwordLabel = new Label("Password:");
        grid.add(passwordLabel, 0, 3);

        cpfLabel = new Label("Cpf:");
        grid.add(cpfLabel, 0, 4);

        addressLabel = new Label("Address:");
        grid.add(addressLabel, 0, 5);

        nameField = new TextField();
        grid.add(nameField, 1, 1);
        emailField = new TextField();
        grid.add(emailField, 1, 2);

        passwordField = new PasswordField();
        grid.add(passwordField, 1, 3);

        cpfField = new TextField();
        grid.add(cpfField, 1, 4);

        addressField = new TextField();
        grid.add(addressField, 1, 5);

        grid.add(infoError, 2, 7);
        submit = new Button("Submit"); 
        // Defines the submit button action
        submit.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        // your registration code here ...
        });

        HBox hbSubmit = new HBox(10);
        hbSubmit.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        hbSubmit.getChildren().add(submit);
        grid.add(hbSubmit, 3, 6);

        // Define a cancelling button and set its action to close the window when activated  
        cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        cancel.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            primaryStage.close();
        });

        HBox hbCancel = new HBox(10);
        hbCancel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbCancel.getChildren().add(cancel);
        grid.add(hbCancel, 0, 6);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: (1-) This is a Swing related question, not a JavaFX.